# Using g++ in Linux mint causing undefined reference to 'Class::Function' (collect2: error)

Tags: c++, linux

Also stoi and exit(0) are both out of scope in stk.cpp and I don't know why.

Here is main.cpp

```
#include "stk.h"

int main()
{
    cout << "REDACTED\n" << endl;
    stk m;
    m.startProg();

}
```

Upon compiling this with `g++ -v main.cpp -o test`  as results in this error:

```
undefined reference to 'stk::startProg()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And here is stk.h

```
#ifndef STK_H
#define STK_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "stdio.h"

using namespace std;


class stk
{
    struct node
    {
        int data;
        node * next;
    };
    node *head;

    public:
        stk()
        {
            head = NULL;
        }
        int push(int val);
        int pop();
        int display();
        int reverse(node * temp);
        void insertAtBottom(int tVal, node * temp);
        bool isEmpty();
        int startProg();
    private:
};

#endif
```

And here is the startProg function in stk.cpp

```
    int stk::startProg()
 {
    while (true)
    {
        string line = "\0";
        getline(cin, line);

        if (0 == line.compare(0,4, "push"))
        {
            int val = 0;
            val = stoi(line.substr(5));
            push(val);
        }
        else if(0 == line.compare (0,3, "pop"))
        {
            pop();
        }
        else if (0 == line.compare(0,7, "isempty"))
        {
            printf ("%s\n", isEmpty() ? "true" : "false");
        }
        else if (0 == line.compare(0,7, "reverse"))
        {
            node * top = NULL;
            reverse(top);

        }
        else if (0 == line.compare(0,7, "display"))
        {
            display();
        }
        else if (0 == line.compare(0,4, "quit"))
        {
            exit(0);
        }
```

Formatting failed me, assume all brackets are correct.

Comment: You aren't linking `stk.o` when you compile `main.cpp`.

Comment: Off topic: Use `exit(0);` with caution. This program is relatively simple, so it is safe here, but [`exit` kills the program like a blow from a headsman's axe.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/exit) Destructors don't get called, resources may not be put away, bad stuff like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are *not* linking the code from stk.cpp when creating the executable.

Solution 1: Compile the .cpp files first and then link.

```
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -c stk.cpp
g++ main.o stk.o -o test
```

Solution 2: Compile and link both files in one step.

```
g++ main.cpp stk.cpp -o test
```

Comment: Excellent, I fixed what my issue was it was what you were saying except I wasn't using g++ -std=c++11