# "undefined symbols for architecture" error when I initialize vector in a separate c++ file

Tags: c++

so I'm very new to programming and I have recently come across an error I am unable to figure out. I have a main.cpp file and a functions.cpp file, and in main I do something like this:

```
string word;
vector<string> vec1;
func1(word, &vec1); //where func1 is located in functions.cpp
```

Then, in the implementation of func1 in functions.cpp, I have something like this:

```
while (getline(cin, word)) {
      vec1.push_back(word);
}
```

And it is giving me two errors. One is "error command failed with linker command 1" (which I have seen many times before, but is implying a different error in this case)

and

"Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: func1(....); referenced from _main in main.o". I have searched for an adequate answer for this error as well and have not been able to figure it out.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here and how I can resolve the error?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Maybe the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34939642/using-g-in-linux-mint-causing-undefined-reference-to-classfunction-collec.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. It was simply a small difference in my declaration in the .h file versus that in my .cpp file